# I want to get an associative array form a JavaScript object list

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a JavaScript object like

```
<pre>
{
 1:{taxCalculation: 39.95, taxId: "3"},
 2:{taxCalculation: 10,    taxId: "3"},
 5:{taxCalculation: 0.48,  taxId: "2"}
}
</pre>
```

I want to create an associative array from the object like below

```
<pre>
 [
  1:{taxCalculation: 39.95, taxId: "3"},
  2:{taxCalculation: 10,    taxId: "3"},
  5:{taxCalculation: 0.48,  taxId: "2"}
 ]
</pre>
```

Comment: This is not valid JSX syntax. In your first example, the {} signifies you're starting to write javascript, but your inner code is not valid JS. In your second example, you can't pass an array like that without wrapping it in {}. Please update your question to be a valid snippet

Comment: That's not an array at all. Did you mean to create an array of three objects?

Comment: @AnilRedshift don't you mean `{}`?

Comment: thanks, edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say your object is called `myObject`. You can simply create an array in Javascript like below.

```
let myArray = [];

Object.keys(myObject).forEach((key, index) => {
  myArray[key] = myObject[key];
});
```

Your new Array myArray should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using ES6 syntax

```js
var obj = {
  1: {taxCalculation: 39.95, taxId: "3"},
  2: {taxCalculation: 10,    taxId: "3"},
  5: {taxCalculation: 0.48,  taxId: "2"}
}


let answer = [...Object.values(obj)]

console.log(answer)
```